# How to use coalesce instead of IS NULL>

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I don't know how to get the to the one retrieved by:

```
SELECT 
    AddressLine1 + ', ' + AddressLine2 AS Address,  
    City  
FROM
    [Person].[Address] 
WHERE 
    [AddressLine1] is not null 
    AND [AddressLine2] is not null
```

I need to use `COALESCE()` function. Every time I try it gets errors. How should I use `coalesce()` to get the same?

Comment: `Coalesce` and `is null` are 2 different expressions.  Use `coalesce` if you have a column with `null` values and you want to convert those values to a different value (but of the same data type).  For example, `where colaesce(addressline1,'') <> ''`...

Comment: COALESCE is a syntactic sugar for the CASE expression with a ELSE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. `COALESCE` is a function that returns the first non-null value.

I think you intended to write this query:

```
SELECT AddressLine1 +', '+ AddressLine2 AS Address, City FROM [Person].[Address] 
WHERE COALESCE([AddressLine1], [AddressLine2]) is not null
```

It will have the same effect as:

```
SELECT AddressLine1 +', '+ AddressLine2 AS Address, City FROM [Person].[Address] 
WHERE [AddressLine1] is not null OR [AddressLine2] is not null
```

The difference between `OR` in this query vs `AND` in yours is small, but oh so important. Apart from that, it's not much shorter, faster or better readable, so I don't think this is a good use case for COALESCE.

Comment: Also, the use of a function in a where filter will make it more or less impossible for the query optimizer to use any statistics or indexes, unless there is a computed column with the same definition.

Comment: Yes, I do know it's not a good idea but that's the one of tasks from databases course. OR is far from AND, but it's nice to have both cases with COALESCE.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(AddressLine1, '') +', '+ COALESCE(AddressLine2, '') AS Address, City
FROM [Person].[Address];
```

That way you can do the string concatenation, even when the values are `NULL`.

Comment: It's showing only the AddressLine1 plus coma and space and then nothing. And it does 'nothing' with the second column.